# Creating a low latency RTP MPEGTS H.264 pipeline with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg2-ts

I'm writing a Qt 5.15 application that should play an **RTP / MPETGS / H.264** video on Linux [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

I'm running [GStreamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) 1.16.3.

Since I'm new to GStreamer, I made everything step by step starting from official tutorials... at this moment I'm able to play an **RTP / H.264** stream almost realtime.

Now the last step (adding **MPEGTS** support) seems to be the hardest.

My source to make a test is [an MP4 H.264 QuickTime file](https://test-videos.co.uk/bigbuckbunny/mp4-h264), and I stream it over the network through `gst-launch`.

The working **RTP / H.264** output pipeline is the following shell command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000;
```

To test the input pipeline without messing up the Qt/C++ code, I use another shell command like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink;
```

AFAIK, if the shell input pipeline works, it will work in my C++ code (of course *elements* after `avdec_h264` depends on my programming/running environment, but if someone needs it I can share without problem).

To add `mpegts` support, I tried with these lines (the last of a long sequence of trials):

```
OUTPUT:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000;

INPUT:
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsparse ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink;
```

It works, but the video seems to **stumble/bounce** while playing.

What I'm missing?

As a side question, I would like to avoid to re-encode the video of the source prior sending it trough RTP. I would like to remove such elements from the output pipeline:

```
avdec_h264 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency
```

I tried, but the result goes from nothing to this,

[image]

if I add the `config-interval=-1` parameter to `h264parse`.

Please note that I would like to keep the latency as low as possible.

--- UPDATE ---

I tried putting a `queue` element between `rtpmp2tdepay` and `tsparse` and this makes video playing fluid, but latency grows to seconds while playing *RTP / H.264*, only it's nearly real-time.

Since MPEGTS is only a transport protocol, why should it add more delay than actual encoding?

Is there a way to shorten this delay? No matter if it changes the whole pipeline as long as protocols and encoding are kept the same.

BTW, I tried tuning `max-size-buffers` size, but using values under 150 will cause play to stumble.

--- UPDATE ---

If I use VLC to create the output stream using the same file, things get even worse:

```
*:sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=5000,mux=ts} :no-sout-all :sout-keep*
```

It is the same stumbling and scrambled video without a chance to fix it:

[image]

Comment: Try testing ...  | mpegtsmux alignment=7 | rtpmp2tpay

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/mpegtsmux/GstBaseTsMux.html?gi-language=c#GstBaseTsMux:alignment

Comment: @Keivan it doesn't reduce the latency very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial fix to the latency problem and *compatibility* with **VLC**:

```
! autovideosink sync=false
```

Disabling the clock synchronisation allows to shorten delays, and also VLC output streaming is now collected correctly by GStreamer.

This also makes the `queue` element unnecessary (not in the general use case probably), and AFAIK also `tsparse` is redundant.

Anyway, I still **need to understand why I need to re-encode H.264 video** (in the output pipeline).

Comment: it seems that the ultimate need for h264 re-encoding is the high bitrate of the original file... it has a bitrate of 25601308 .. could anyone confirm ?